# Use adminer in windows with xampp

Tags: php, xampp

How to setup Adminer with Xampp in Windows 10 ?

I need to steps to set the Adminer with Xampp

Is there any .exe file for windows system ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there any `.exe` file for Windows?

Yes. Download the [XAMPP installer from Apache Friends](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html).

> How do I setup Adminer with XAMPP in Windows 10?

1. Install XAMMP (above).
2. [Download the Adminer `.php` file](https://www.adminer.org/)
3. Place this file in your `XAMPP/htdocs` directory.
4. Start Apache from the XAMMP Control Panel.
5. Go to something like `http://localhost/name-of-the-file-you-downloaded.php` in your browser.
6. Enter the correct information to log in to your database.